# SQL How to find average of many sums of groups only if the groups follow certain rules

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, bigdata

Here is my current code:

```
SELECT
AVG(famTotal)

FROM `OmniHealth.new2015Data`, (
SELECT
SUM( TOTEXP15 ) as famTotal
FROM `OmniHealth.new2015Data` 

GROUP BY DUID
)
WHERE BMINDX53 BETWEEN 0 AND 25 AND
ADSMOK42 = -1 AND
FCSZ1231 = 7
```

What I want to do is find the average cost per family where the family has all members with BMI between 0 and 25, don't smoke, and the family is an arbitrary size.

The spending data is on a per person basis in the table, so I'm trying to sum it based on the "dwelling unit ID" (DUID) being the same for all of the people, and then averaging the total per family as long as the family only has the properties I stated in the last paragraph.

Thank you for the replies! I'm new at SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider joining two aggregate query derived tables that matches on count to align all household members to all household members with specific conditions.

```
SELECT AVG(t1.famTotal) as famTotal

FROM
  (SELECT DUID, Count(*) As GrpCount, SUM(TOTEXP15) as famTotal
   FROM `OmniHealth.new2015Data` 
   GROUP BY DUID) As t1

INNER JOIN

  (SELECT DUID, Count(*) As GrpCount
   FROM `OmniHealth.new2015Data` 
   WHERE BMINDX53 BETWEEN 0 AND 25 
     AND ADSMOK42 = -1 
     AND FCSZ1231 = 7
   GROUP BY DUID) As t2

ON t1.DUID = t2.DUID AND t1.GrpCount = t2.GrpCount
```

Comment: This is close but its giving me data that I know can't be correct. For example, when I try it with different family sizes, such as 3, I'll get a lower number for a higher family size, and one try I got a super low number where it shouldn't be. Can you explain what the `Count(*) as GrpCount` is doing in this?

Comment: I cannot help further without sample data. But your issue may be a data issue not this SQL logic. To check underlying records, replace `AVG(...)` in outer query with asterisk `*`. Then, check hhld members under specific *DUID*. Manually sum total exp to verify.

Comment: And `Count(*)` basically counts the records in the group. Since you need all family members to align to your criteria then the conditional group count should equal full group count.

Comment: If I add the `*` in place of `AVG(t1.famTotal)` I get this error: `Error: Syntax error: Unexpected keyword AS at [1:10]` from Google BigQuery.

Comment: however, when I add a WHERE qualifier  in both of the inner querys and I get null when I put in a specific DUID that I found.

Comment: Hmmm...not familiar with Google BigQuery but by SQL standards that should have worked. Try `t1.*` or actual named columns: `SELECT t1.DUID, t1.GrpCount, t1.famTotal`. Then investigate a specific *DUID*.

Comment: So the `t1.*` is valid but it returns zero results when run. I will get a sample of the data for you to check out.

Comment: Here is a download link to sample data. [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=12167702971985622761)

Comment: Please post a sample of your data in the body of your question. See *edit* link. Links will break in future and can be unsecure. If zero results return, there may not be any family with ALL members sharing your criteria (i.e., all smokers and `FCSZ1231 = 7`). Play around with different criteria.

Comment: I added the sample link, but I think you solved it. There weren't any 7 person families meeting the criteria

Comment: When I do the `t1.*` I get some rows with `GrpCount` being two different sets of numbers, is that how it should be? And if so which one is it averaging?

Comment: Good to hear. *GrpCount* from *t1* and *t2* should both be the same for both per their `JOIN`. To average the *famTotal* sums, you would need to return back to `AVG()` in outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT DUID, AVG(TOTEXP15) AS famAverage
FROM `OmniHealth.new2015Data` 
GROUP BY DUID
HAVING MIN(BMINDX53) >=0 AND MAX(BMINDX53) <=25
AND MIN(ADSMOK42) = -1 AND MAX(ADSMOK42) = -1
AND MIN(FCSZ1231) = 7 AND MAX(FCSZ1231) = 7
```